# passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, strcpy

```c
char getString(char *str, int length, char field[20])
{
    printf(" %s: ", field);
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(str, length, stdin);
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';
    fflush(stdin);
    return *str;
}
```

why i can't use strcpy in this case

```c
strcpy(newContact->fieldsValue[i], getString(newContact->fieldsValue[i], 30, listFieldsName[i]));
```

i want to get value of fieldName

```c
struct newContact = {
char *fieldsName[30],
char *fieldsValue[30],
struct newContact* next;
}
char *listFieldsName = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

Comment: You can't use `strcpy` because `strcpy` is used to copy strings. You only provide a single `char`. That is not a string. Strings are nul-termianted character sequences. Unless your string has length 0 it won't fit into a single `char`. And even in that case, you would need to provide the address of that `char`.

Comment: Not your question, but: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code please? You've blamed it on stackoverflow, but most people asking questions manage to format their code without backslashes...

Comment: sorry, i will fix formatting of my code

Answer (score 0):

### Undefined Behaviour:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

Flushing stdin invokes undefined behaviour.

From C11:

> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the
> most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any
> unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment
> to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

- Once the abstract state machine reaches an undefined state, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution of the program can be made.

---

*Re: Why can't I use strcpy in this case?*

### Invalid arguments to `strcpy`:

From C11:

> The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the
> terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1. If
> copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
> undefined.

The function `strcpy` takes the source string and destination string, where a string is an array of null-terminated bytes.

*Answer:* `getstring` returns a `char`, not a `char *`.  You're passing a `char` in place of a `char *` to `strcpy`.

Comment: but im using fgets so i cant return char in getString()

Comment: You don't need to return anything. Just call the function before ```strcpy``` and pass ```str``` directly to it. But it's hard to tell what you're trying to do without seeing your code. Kindly edit the question to provide a minimal reproducible example.